# Gradle composite builds version ingredients and maven publish

Tags: gradle, build, multi-module

The documentation of gradle mentions regarding composite builds that maven-publish style builds are a known limitation. 
To what extent? Will it not work at all if maven-publish is used?

Also how can I ensure proper versioning? Is 
Git submodules the preferred solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are some great videos on youtube explaining composite builds. Git submodules are not required to use them.

Regarding limitations: `project.name / group` need to mach for the substituted dependency

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you elaborate on 'Regarding limitations: project.name / group need to mach for the substituted dependency'? Do you have an example or reference to an solution?